# gcloud file transfer does not show error but does not appear either

Tags: gcloud

I'm trying to transfer files to my virtual machine instance on GCP using the gcloud client using `gcloud compute scp --recurse ./local-repo foo:~/` and it looks like the files transfer, but once I ssh into `foo`, I don't see anything. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: List the destination computer's users in the `/home` directory `ls -l /home`. Execute this command from your source computer: `gcloud auth list`. Note the active account. On the Linux VM, the files will have been copied to `/home/[user-id]` because you used the `~` variable.

Comment: thank you! that was it. I assumed that only one user was allowed or would be used for this.